# Inline functions in dotNet 3.0+ with C#?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, inline-method

I am looking for a trick in newer dotnets where I can use inline functions that return a string value. Here's what I have:

```
var split = new[] { " " };
var words = SearchTextBox.Text.Trim().Split(
              split, 
              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var textQuery = /*inlinefunction that operates on words array and returns a string.*/
```

I know I've seen this before maybe with chain methods or anonymous functions...
I just can't recall if I imagined the whole thing or not :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you thinking of LINQ?

```
var textQuery = words.Select(word => word.ToLower());
```

Comment: Some days I am very very dumb :-)

Comment: This doesn't return a string however, but an `IEnumerable<string>`. If you want a single string, you should combine the above answer with Joren's suggestion of using `String.Join`. Weird by the way that `Join` takes an array, anyone know why it doesn't take an `IEnumerable` or an `IList`?

Comment: String.Join() was introduced in .NET 1.0, but generics only came in .NET 2.0.

Comment: I think Matt meant that the mapping function returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're thinking about linq to objects, perhaps with a `.First()` at the end to get a string.

```
var textQuery = words.Where(w => w.Length > 5).First();
```

The key to making all the work are lamdba expression and `IEnumerable<T>` and it's associated extension methods. It's not limited to strings.

Answer (score 1):

To get a string out of a query (or any other IEnumerable), you can use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx).
Example:

```
string result = String.Join(" ", textQuery.ToArray());
```

So use LINQ like the other answers suggest to operate on 'words', then use String.Join to recombine them into a string.